# Keyboard shortcut to open an attachement in thunderbird

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

Is there a keyboard shortcut to open an attachement(s) in thunderbird without using the mouse when the message is selected in the message list? If not, is there a way to define a custom one?

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts#w_message-functions

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I didn't find what I want in your link. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Why the downvote? Please leave a comment of what is wrong with the question and how to improve it before downvoting!

Comment: "Is there a keyboard shortcut to open an attachement(s) in thunderbird" If it's not listed there, then presumably there isn't one, so I'm not sure why you're asking if there is. This conveys a lack of research, and not doing research tends to garner down-votes. PS: while it's a nicety, no one owes an explanation for their anonymous votes; hover over the down-vote arrow with your mouse for a tooltip containing the basic reasons for DV'ing. Regarding creating your own, check out AutoHotkey or alike.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 There may be a keyboard shorcut which is not documented, there may also be a addon which adds this feature there may also be a way to modify a config file to get this done... So I googled but didn't find anything, that's why I am asking here. AutoHotkey seems to be for windows. I am using linux (added tag).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a quick keystroke, but there are ways to do it.

I'm writing this from a Windows machine, but I'm pretty sure it's similar on Linux. And I use an addon called AttachmentExtractor, so I don't quite remember the "stock" menu items, but this may work for you too:

```
Alt+M, H, O
```

Or, use Enter to open the message, and then

```
Tab, [selects the attachment area]
Space, [expands it]
arrow keys, [if you need to select among attachments]
Enter
```

I'm not sure about custom shortcuts, but this may be relevant:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension